# Create-react-app shows white page for milliseconds while refreshing

Tags: reactjs

I hosted my create-react-app on AWS. My app is still static, no connection to any backend. My problem is that a white page shows up for a very short period when i refresh my site then the actual page shows up. It is disturbing for users. I removed unused packages and updated all my dependencies and i still have the same issue. I checked my resource file in the network tab in console log it is 5.8 mb. Am i having the issue because my file is big? If yes how would I solve it.
I am trying to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the developing mode, it is normal to have not-optimized performance. You can check about "Developing mode vs production mode in reactjs". You can `build` your `create-react-app` and then see whether the problem persists.